# What is meant by $P(X = x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is meant by the statement $P(X = x) = \theta$? As in, what is its English translation? I'm assuming that $X$ is a random variable and $x$ is a member of its sample space.

Is it just "the probability that event $x$ occurs for random variable $X$ is equal to $\theta$"?

If so, why use the "$=$" sign inside the parentheses? Isn't that technically misleading since the random variable $X$ is not equal to one of its sample space members $x$?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is "The probability that the random variable $X$ takes the value $x$ is equal to $\theta$." The notation is a bit misleading. You are right that $X$ does not equal $x$, but rather, after a measurement of $X$ is made, the value $x$ is observed as a result.

Comment: What do you mean "after a measurement of $X$ is made"? Is the term "measurement" here being used in a technical sense?

Comment: A random variable describes a observable whose quantity is not uniquely determined, but is subject to chance variation according to some distribution. A measurement is the act of "observing" this random variable. This could be a technical measurement, like reading a thermometer. But it could also be something like counting the number of home runs in a season for a baseball team, or recording stock prices.

Comment: Hmmm... I am afraid this post can only confuse *more* the OP. Better to stick to solid definitions (what does "measurement" refer to, exactly?), no?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your probability space is $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ and $X$ be a random variable defined on this probability space. Technically, 
$$P(X= x) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) = x\}) := P(E) $$

Having said $X$ is a random variable, $E = X^{-1}((-\infty, x])\backslash X^{-1}((-\infty, x))\in \mathscr{F}$, hence it does make sense to say the probability of $E$, where $E$ is an event of the $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: So $P(X = x) = P(P^{-1}(x))$?

Comment: @PP121 $P(X = x) = P(X^{-1}(\{x\}))$. I guess you made a typo.

Comment: Ok. Does the definition of $P(X=x)$ change if $X$ is NOT a random variable, and instead just some paramater for which $x$ is a candidate for its value?

Comment: If $X$ is not a random variable, it is illegal to write $P(X = x)$ unless you know based on other information that $\{X = x\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}$. Because in principle probabilities are only assigned to those events in $\mathscr{F}$. Without assuming $X$ is a random variable, it is not guaranteed that $\{X = x\} \in \mathscr{F}$, i.e., $X^{-1}(\{x\})$ could be non-measurable.

Answer (score -1):

The statement $\Bbb P(X=x)=\theta$ reads

> The probability that $X$ is equal to $x$ is $\theta$.

For example, consider the experiment of rolling one standard fair six-sided die once. Then our sample space is
$$
S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}
$$
Now, let $X:S\to\Bbb R$ be given by the formula
$$
X(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x\text{ not prime} \\
2 & x \text{ even prime} \\
3 & x\text{ odd prime} 
\end{cases}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\Bbb P(X=1)&=\frac{1}{2}&\Bbb P(X=2)&=\frac{1}{6}&\Bbb P(X=3)&=\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

Note that the restrictions on the possible values of $\theta$ are quite severe if our random variable is *continuous*. Indeed, let $X$ be a random variable with [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) $f$. Then
$$
\Bbb P(X=x)=\Bbb P(x\leq X\leq x)=\int_x^x f(t)\,dt=0
$$

Comment: $X$ is a function. The statement that, ie, "the probability that $X$ is equal to $1$" seems to be nonsensical.

Comment: I suppose you are correct but this abuse of notation and language is pervasive and, in my opinion, not harmful.

Comment: @Zhanxiong gives a rigorous definition

Comment: @PP21 First you wrote: "$X$ is a random variable." That is a good description. Now you write: "$X$ is a function." Why?

Comment: Because random variables are functions.